# Exclude a folder from React build deployment to GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I would like to exclude a subfolder, `assets`, from the `public` folder containing some JSON files when I deploy my React build to GitHub Pages. I am wanting to do this because I run a workflow action weekly to update those files from a third-party API and don't wish to overwrite them since my local files are older and don't need to be updated for development purposes.

I've tried removing the folder with `del build\\assets` prior to deployment, but that just deletes the folder from my `gh-pages` branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude certain file(s) by doing this, so add whatever old version of file you want to keep in github, then exclude it further while staging any changes:

`git add --all -- :!main/fileToExclude.FileType`

Another way is to add all files for changes and then exclude one after:

`git reset -- main/fileToExclude.FileType`